# Python & OpenPYXL - writing to corresponding cell in same row

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

It is my first time using openpyxl. I am processing an XLSX file that contains content in UTF-8. I want to process all of the cells in column BF. In essence, my logic is below:-

- for each cell in column BF, assign the content to a variable
- if the variable is not a string, move on to the next row
- if the variable is a string, perform a process on that string which then generates a new variable
- write this variable to the corresponding row in column BG (in essence, the same row)

My code is below:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

filepath = 'myfile.xlsx'

wb = load_workbook(filepath)

source = wb["sheet1"]
for cell in source['BF']:
    message = cell.value
    if type(message) == 'str':
        print(message)
        # perform an action against the 'message' and then write output of this action to corresponding cell in column BG
```

I just don't know how to identify the corresponding cell. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Just reassign whatever you do with the value to the cell: `cell.value = …`

Answer (score -1):

1. `cell.row` will give you the row number.
2. you can 'grab' the range of 'BG' at first, and then acces the cells by row number.
   `col_bg = source["BG"]`

so:

```py
# perform an action against the 'message' and then write output of this action to corresponding cell in column BG
col_bg[cell.row].value = 'modified value' #refer to selected range "BG" at row same as the cell in BF
```

Comment: The index here will be off by one but it's also not necessary to look the cell up, when you already have it.

Comment: @CharlieClark, we have the cell in "B**F**", not in "B**G**".

Comment: Doesn't matter, just use the offset.

Comment: @CharlieClark, you can use ```cell.offset```, but sometimes there are deleted columns or not in the order you expect.

Comment: The order of columns never changes.